# Can two vectors be linearly dependent if they are perpendicular?

Tags: vectors

Can two perpendicular vectors to each other  be linearly dependent and can two parallel vectors to each other  be linearly independent ?

Comment: 1) Yes, if one of them is zero. 2) No.

Comment: So if non of two perpendicular vectors is 0 then they cant be linearly dependent right ?

Comment: ^ Yes that's right

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Slightly strengthening 1): if and only if.

Comment: but isn't the 0 vector perpendicular to any vector ?

Comment: @EndritShabani If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every set which contains mutually perpendicular vectors is a independent set. All the vectors in this set are independent. You can search for Gram-Schmidt process. In that process it makes an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$. There you can easily see why a set of mutually perpendicular vectors are independent.

If two vectors are parallel then each of them is a non-zero scalar multiple of other one unless one of them is zero. In both situation they form a dependent set